# What kind of lock is this, and how can I replace it?

Tags: windows, lock

This is the lock barrel from one of my window handles - the key jammed in it and when I pulled the key out, the barrel came with it. You can see on the photo where a small metal lug has snapped off, so presumably this was what was holding the barrel in the handle.

[image: First angle of the lock barrel]
[image: Second angle of the lock barrel]
[image: Handle the barrel came out of]

What is this type of lock barrel called, where can I buy a replacement in the UK, and how would I fit it when I get one?

Comment: It's a disc tumbler lock.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the lower picture, you'll see that the missing tab served to hold the plug in its recessed (locked) position. When rotated 90 degrees it lined up with the cut-outs, letting the spring (lost, I presume?) push it out to the unlocked position.

It *may* also have helped retain the plug in the lock. More commonly, that's actually done by a reserved wafer, so the plug can be removed and rekeyed by cutting a modified key (or by picking). If you had a new key cut recently and the new key is a bit longer or otherwise not identical, you may have unintentionally engaged that function.

If you contact the window's manufacturer -- or the lock's manufacturer if it's an aftermarket addition -- they may be able to send you a new plug with instructions for installing it. If you give them the key number they can probably issue one that responds to the same key. If you can't find a brandname, a locksmith *may* be able to take measurements and track it down.

Note, however, that the lock cylinder is not required to operate the latch, only to make it tamper-resistant. So you could leave it as it is, or just shove the plug back into the lock and operate it as a manual bolt rather than one that automatically pops out when you turn the key. Not as secure as it was originally,  but more so than leaving the cylinder out.